# Passing HTML variable to python

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to pass my html form data to python using flask, however I'm not 100% sure where I'm going wrong

**Python**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/form', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    your_name = request.form['your_name']
        customer_number = request.form['customer_number']
        msg = request.form['msg']

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

This my from from  **HTML**

```
<form action="smssend.py" method="post">
  <label for="msg">Message</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="50"> </textarea> <br>
  <label for="your_name">Your Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" /> <br>
  <label for="customer_number">Customers Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="customer_number" id="customer_number" /> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: when i hit submit on my html, it just opens my python script in my web browser, it doesn't appear to be executing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the action to the URL that handles the request like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/form" method="post"> ... </form>
```

ofc change the URL according to your setup.

Comment: this just returns python code in text i'm a bit confused how to get this working